# How to find the exact value of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos \pi x}{x^{2}-2 x+2} d x$?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, contour-integration

I am going to evaluate the exact value of the integral
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (\pi x)}{x^{2}-2 x+2} d x
$$
using contour integration along anti-clockwise direction of the path
$$\gamma=\gamma_{1} \cup \gamma_{2} \textrm{ where }  \gamma_{1}(t)=t+i 0(-R \leq t \leq R)  \textrm{ and } \gamma_{2}(t)=R e^{i t}  (0<t<\pi) $$

$$
\begin{aligned}
& \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (\pi x)}{x^{2}-2 x+2} d x \\
=& \operatorname{Re}\left[2 \pi i \operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{e^{\pi z i}}{z^{2}-2 z+2}, 1+i\right)\right]\\
=& \operatorname{Re}\left[2 \pi i \frac{e^{\pi(1+i) i}}{2(1+i)-2}\right] \\
=& \pi \operatorname{Re}\left[e^{\pi(i-1)}\right] \\
=& \frac{\pi}{e^{\pi}} \operatorname{Re}\left(e^{\pi i}\right)\\
=&-\pi e^{-\pi}
\end{aligned}
$$

**Are there any other methods?**

Comment: Yes, there are other methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize the known integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos \pi x}{x^{2}+1} d x=\pi e^{-\pi}$ to integrate

\begin{align}
&\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos \pi x}{x^{2}-2 x+2} dx
\overset{x=y+1}=-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos \pi y}{y^2+1} d y=-\pi e^{-\pi}
\end{align}

Comment: Wonderful translation make simple!

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{1}{x^2-2 x+2}=\frac i 2\Bigg[\frac{1}{x-(1-i)} -\frac{1}{x-(1+i)}\Bigg]$$ Then, we have two integrals
$$I_a=\int \frac{\cos(\pi x)}{x-a} \,dx=\cos (\pi  a)\, \text{Ci}(\pi  x-\pi a  )+\sin (\pi  a) \,\text{Si}(a \pi -\pi  x)$$

$$2\int \frac{\cos(\pi x)}{x^2-2 x+2}\,dx=$$
$$i \cosh (\pi ) (\text{Ci}(\pi  ((1+i)-x))-\text{Ci}(-\pi  (x-(1-i))))+$$$$\sinh (\pi )
   (\text{Si}(\pi  (x-(1-i)))-\text{Si}(\pi  ((1+i)-x)))$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(\pi x)}{x^2-2 x+2}\,dx=\frac{\pi}{2}   (\sinh (\pi )-2 \cosh (\pi ))+\frac{1}{2} \pi  \sinh (\pi )=-\pi\,e^{-\pi}$$

Comment: Interesting partial fractions with Cosc and Sinc functions.